# SAAS MDM/MAM solution for deploy in-house iOS application

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, deployment, mdm

I'm searching for a SAAS solution for MDM/MAM management to deploy our in-house developed iOS application.

It’s for a small company (5 devices), and MDM/MAM providers like AirWatch or XenMobile only offer such a service for bigger companies (AirWatch price is for min. 25 devices in Spain)

Our company is located in Spain, so Safe Harbor or Europe Located Servers is a must have.

Any advice?

Thanks,

Alex Bibiano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot use Testflight because if I have understant it right, you have to submit the app for Beta App Review to Apple in order to aprove it before distribute it to External users and we don't want to do it.

Finnaly we use [hockeyapp](http://hockeyapp.net/features/). It's free for 2 apps and works like Testflight or other MAMs.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try testflight?
If you do insist on mdm, try Meraki. It is free.